# Where to complete TransactionScope in using statements?

Tags: c#, dispose

I'm using two SQLConnection in a TransactionScope is this (pseudo)code correct?

```
using (TransactionScope ts= new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
  {
     using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
       {
         (...)
       }

     using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString2))
        {
           (...)
        }

     ts.Complete();
   }
```

or should I use this one?

```
using (TransactionScope ts= new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
  {
     using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
       {
         (...)
         using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString2))
          {
             (...)
             ts.Complete();
          }
       }
   }
```

The first code is nicer as it allows me to extract the command in methods. However my fear is that in this case the connections are disposed before the completion of the scope, is the enlistment into the TransactionScope enough to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem at all calling `Complete` after the nested connections are disposed.  The lifetime of the transaction is intentionally larger than that of the SQL connection, and you can continue to interact with it independent of the lifetime of any other connections.

So yes, in your first example you are calling `Complete` after the connection is disposed, *and that's perfectly fine*.

You can see, based on the examples in the documentation for [Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) as well as [this page on how to use transaction scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx) that the transaction can be completed after the connection has been disposed.

Comment: Following Servy advice I have written my code following the first sample and I was able to test that its behave as expected (the connection are roll-backed if no .Complete()is called on the Transaction scope

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, both connections are disposed before ts.Complete() is called, which is not a problem, since the ts.Complete() method does not use the connections:

- both connections are declared locally inside this method and would be out of scope for any other method
- the connections are not passed to the ts.Complete() method to bring them into scope

In your second example, the ts.Complete() method is called when both connections are still alive, however, they are not passed to the method and can therefore not be used.

This means that both methods will work equally well and it is irrelevant whether or not the connections are disposed before ts.Complete() is called.

Comment: `If you need to call ts.Complete() before the connections are disposed of` And what makes you think that needs to be done?  I see no indication that it needs to be done.

Comment: @Servy From the OP: `However my fear is that in this case the connections are disposed before the completion of the scope`.

Comment: Yes, and they are, *and that's not a problem at all*.  That's what the correct answer is.

Comment: @Servy I'm not the one who came up with that requirement. I have no experience with this particular case subject, just trying to explain the concept of the `using` statement. Why don't you put together your own answer then.

Comment: I was simply looking for a more official reference stating it before writing an answer.

Comment: @Servy To me it sounded like you thought my answer made no sense, but I understand what you are getting at and you're right.

Comment: Well, the second half of your answer isn't really relevant, only the top portion is.  It's also not wrong, because you state that it's dependent on an assumption on the start.  However, because the assumption that you make at the start is wrong, the rest of it simply doesn't apply.  `If you need to call [...]` well, since you don't, you don't need to do the rest of it.  Nothing there is wrong, it just doesn't really say anything at all.

Comment: @Servy Okay, I re-read the whole thing and the OP and you're right. I edited my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the MSDN site it looks like the second one is the one to use...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx (see the first example)

Comment: The example calls `Complete` after the end of the `using` block for the connections, so it's actually following the first example, not the second.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third possibility:

```
using (TransactionScope ts= new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString2))
{
    // ...
    ts.Complete()
}
```

Comment: that's the same as the second one he mentioned, just without the { }